# How am I able to use int32_t without without using std?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, header, namespaces

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int32_t i = 5;
    std::cout << "i: " << i << '\n';
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra foo.cpp && ./a.out 
i: 5
```

Here is my question:

The C++ standard appears to define `int32_t` in `cstdint` within the `std` namespace.

In my code, I have neither included `cstdint` nor do I use the `std` namespace. Why does the compiler not complain then?

Comment: Seems like `iostream` already includes `cstdint`

Comment: Standard headers may (or may not) include other standard headers.  You should always include the headers your program needs.

Comment: @IanA.B.King It does not include the `std` namespace by default because I am forced to use `std::cout`. Why was I not forced to use `std::int32_t`?

Comment: You stumbled upon an implementation detail, that's all. The only **portable** thing to do is to include `cstdint` and use `std::int32_t`. That's all.

Comment: @StoryTeller Using `int32_t` without `std::` is implementation-dependent too? Doesn't the standard require it should be put in `std` namespace?

Comment: @IanA.B.King: 10k+ users can still see your deleted answer, and the comments that made the reasons for the downvotes are loud and clear. Please don't answer in comments as comments cannot be peer reviewed.

Comment: @songyuanyao - If you include `cstdint` then yes, only `std::int32_t` is guaranteed to exist. On the flip side `stdint.h` only guarnatees `::int32_t` to exist (if it's defined at all on the system).

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm still trying to get a reason of why my answer was either bad in quality, content, or whatever else.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I think avoiding peer review is the point of that comment

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks that makes sense.

Comment: @IanA.B.King I don't think the standard guarantees that `int32_t` must be *declared* in the *default* namespace by `cstdint`. Do you have the exact section number of the standard that says that `int32_t` is indeed *declared* within `cstdint` in the *default* namespace?

Comment: @Bathsheba Hey look! It says that int32_t is defined in <cstdint>. What a coincidence!

Comment: `+1 and -4` is hardly mass downvoting. Bo's answer is the more correct superset of yours: those types _may_ be declared in the global namespace, but _must_ be available in namespace `std`. It's not portable to depend on them being available in the global namespace (as, to be fair, plenty of my own code does for brevity).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name `int32_t` also appears in the global scope of the C library header `stdint.h`. This might make it globally visible also in C++.

The section [[Headers]](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#headers-4) says:

> ... the contents of each header *cname* is the same as that of the corresponding header *name.h* as specified in the C standard library.
>   In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope of the namespace std.
>   **It is unspecified whether these names** (including any overloads added in [language.support] through [thread] and [depr]) **are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations**.

The standard also has [a blanket statement](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#res.on.headers-1):

> A C++ header may include other C++ headers.

So by including `<iostream>` you are *guaranteed* to see the stream objects, but might *also* happen to get access to some other library features as well.

As these indirect includes are unspecified, the result varies between implementations. So the program should always include all the headers it needs, to be portable to a different compiler.